# Should shut down be logged as "crash"?

Tags: macos, crash, shutdown

Some time ago, I started having minor problems.  The "least minor" was that shutdown took more than ten minutes.  With an SSD internal and nothing external, this didn't seem right.

But when I used 'last' one day to check the timing of a recent session, I noticed that every shutdown was labeled "crash."  So I decided to wipe and reinstall.

After reinstall, to avoid re-introducing any problems, I did not use migration assistant.  I created all my user accounts fresh, and did a few app updates.

Before doing a backup of the new system, I used 'last' to see exactly when the install started (so I would know which backups to get old stuff from).  To my surprise, every shutdown, including the ones done by the installer, was labeled "crash."

I know it did not always do this.  Is this a "normal" change of some recent MacOS version?  All the hardware except the RAM and SSD are Apple-refurbs with only five days of the warranty used.  The RAM and SSD came from the old system, which Apple's in-store diagnostics said had no hardware issues.  We did have to "repair disk" but afterward, it passed diagnostics and besides, I erased it completely before the re-install.  Well, not completely—even though I selected the whole drive, Disk Utility saved the recovery partition.

**So (tl;dr)**, is it normal for MacOS 10.12.1 and 10.12.2 to log a crash every time we shut down?